# Not able to decalre the custom pipes in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

shortend.pipe.ts created inside app folder

```
import { PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

export class ShortendPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, ...args: any[]) {
        return value.substr(0, 10)
    }
}
```

while declaring the custom pipe inside the app.module.ts inside the declaration array it is giving array saying only components, directives or pipes are allowed and shortendPipe is none.

How to resolve the above issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you are missing `@Pipe` annotation. https://angular.io/api/core/PipeTransform

Answer (score 1):

My comment as full answer:

You are missing the `@Pipe` annotation. Add the import for `Pipe` and add the annotation for it. e.g.:

```js
import {Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({name: 'shortend'})
export class ShortendPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, ...args: any[]) {
        return value.substr(0, 10)
    }
}
```

See `Usage notes` here: https://angular.io/api/core/PipeTransform

Comment: Thanks , I was following a video tutorial, that's why confused.